# How to move UITableView section to bottom in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am this library for parallax effect.: `https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader`
When i am scrolling tableView up, the section header title  comes on the top of every view.
This is the image when i scroll Table view up, as you can see content of Name and PHONE NUMBER is hidden but title is not hidden.
[image]

I am this code to send  table to bottom of every View but it is not working : `self.tableView.layer.zPosition = 0`.

I tried with many way, but did not find a solution. what may be the solution?

Comment: "the section header title comes on the top of every view"

It's not clear what you meant there. But did you meant on top of every UITableViewCell? Or is the header going out of bound and over the other Views (like the image).

Comment: yes, like the image. section title (name, phone number) is showing on the top of Header. it should hide.

Comment: post an image if you can